# Launching iPhone App - Do I need separate names for the App and the Landing Page/website or can I use the same name?

Tags: ios, iphone, app

I am launching a iPhone App.  Do I need two separate domain names for the app and the landing page website or can I use the same name for both.  The website will solely be used to advertise the app information.

Comment: Use same domain name as two different website would only confuse users.